# How do I scan a batch of colors in an image, then exchange groups of colors for new colors?

Tags: scanning

Using GIMP, how do I scan colors in an image, choose certain of those colors and exchange them for another color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIMP - change color of object preserving feathering](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/gimp-change-color-of-object-preserving-feathering) or [Changing image color](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39277/changing-image-color)

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but I spoke to someone familiar with another more popular program, and he said to see if there is a "laso" tool, which will capture the boundary of whatever color group I need to choose. Then I intend to see if "colorify" will work on only a selected area.